# Differentiating $\sin^3 (3t + 2)$ and $3\sqrt{\cos(2x-1)}$

Tags: calculus

How do I use the chain rule to differentiate $\sin^3(3t+2)$ and $3\sqrt{\cos(2x-1)}$?

I need these two done as examples so that I can do the rest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \sin^3 (3t + 2)=3\sin^2(3t+2)\times\cos{(3t+2)}\times3=9\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)}$

$\displaystyle{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}3(\cos(2x-1))^{1/2} =3\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\times(\cos(2x-1))^{-1/2}\right)\times-\sin(2x-1)\times2=\frac{-3\sin(2x-1)}{\sqrt{\cos(2x-1)}}}$

Comment: thank you very much oliver

Answer (score 1):

$$[\sin^3(3t+2)]'=3\sin^2(3t+2)[\sin(3t+2)]'=3\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)[(3t)'+2']$$
$$=3\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)[3(t)'+0]=3\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)[3\cdot 1]$$
$$=9\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)=9\sin^2(3t+2)\cos(3t+2)$$

$$[3\sqrt{\cos (2x-1)}]'=3[\sqrt{\cos (2x-1)}]'=3\cdot \frac{{[\cos (2x-1)]'}}{2\sqrt{\cos (2x-1)}}$$
$$=3\frac{-(2x-1)'\cdot \sin(2x-1)}{2\sqrt{\cos (2x-1)}}=\frac{-3\sin(2x-1)}{\sqrt{\cos (2x-1)}}$$